# Is it possible to control which files to install from command line for INNO installer?

Tags: inno-setup

I would like to control a subset of files and only allow some of them to be installed if run with a command line switch for instance.

Is this possible?

For example

```
if (some condition)
    install full set of files
else
    Install other set of files
```

Alternatively I can just run another installer but then I have to pass the file/path location to that second installer.  There is also the issue of bundling that second installer with the first one.  I think that part is not that difficult though

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is even rather easy. There are several ways to do this, all of which depend on Pascal scripting.

**Method 1**

- You can use the [`GetCmdTail`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_isxfunc_getcmdtail.htm), [`ParamCount`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_isxfunc_paramcount.htm), and [`ParamStr`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_isxfunc_paramstr.htm) functions to obtain the entire or parts of the command-line.
- Then you can use the [`Check`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_scriptcheck.htm) parameter on separate files. Hence, each file will be installed if and only if the called function returns `true`.

Comment: @Tim: As you might have guessed, I intended to write a **Method 2** also. I wanted to use the command-line to select which *components* to be on and which to be off. But although there is a `IsComponentSelected` function (http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_isxfunc_iscomponentselected.htm), there seems not to be a `SetComponentSelected` procedure...